# How do I reduce contour intervals (i.e. from 50m contours to 10m contours) without using DEM?

Tags: dem

I have shapefiles (lines) of contours having 50m intervals. How can I reduce the intervals to 10m without first converting the 50m contours to DEM?

Comment: short answer: You can't. Long answer: even if you create a DEM from the contours, and then create contours at 10m interval, these really won't give you higher resolution data. It will give you blocky contours.

Comment: This is similar to asking how to generate secondary roads from an interstate highways layer.  While it might be possible to generate *something*, the odds of generating something *valid* is vanishingly small.

Comment: In other words: What elaborate curve interpolation algorithm can i use in order to mislead folks into thinking my data are more precise than they are?

Comment: Dear @DevdattaTengshe,
Thank you for the comments. I got to realise it just was not possible so I gave up.